# Is the object optimized out at compile time when unused?

Tags: java

Brushing up on programming, and java

- JDK 1.6
- IDE Eclipse (Helios)

Having created a simple class with a private ctor as below

```
package learn;

public class Recherche {

    final int iInteger = 0;

    private Recherche() {
    }
}
```

This is invoked from the project entry-point as below

```
package learn;

public class Tutorial {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello Windows 7x64");
            Recherche rech;
            rech = null;
        }
}
```

A break-point as placed in class Recherché at `final int iInteger = 0;`
With the default ctor declared `private`, I expect the application to fail compilation, or die with an exception when executed. Yet both work flawlessly.

Is the object optimized out at compile time thus ignoring the ctor?

Comment: You never create an instance of that object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this line

```
Recherche rech;
```

you did *not* create a `Recherche` object; only a reference variable.  And there is no object here either:

```
rech = null;
```

There is no call to the constructor to optimize out; there is no object and no `int` instance variable to optimize out.

Adding a call to actually create an object will result in the compiler error for the constructor being private:

```
rech = new Recherche();  // can't access private constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the object of the class using new operator,you will find the answer

```
Recherche obj = new Recherche();
```